# directive don't exist in current component

Tags: angular, directive, angular2-directives, file-not-found

I'm new to angular 2, I saw some videos and implement this but I am facing some problems.
I have created a new component navbar and imported it in `app.component.ts` file. While adding meta data @Component directive not found error occurred.

```
Error: Argument of type '{ selector: string; template: string; directive: (typeof NavbarComponent)[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directive' does not exist in type 'Component'.
```

**app.component.ts Code:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
  directive: [NavbarComponent]
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

[image: navbar.component.ts]]

[image: app.component.ts]]

Comment: Author of those videos was using old version of Angular. Now, the component decorator's metadata type has changed and no longer provide a `directive` field.

Comment: how can I do that in the new version?

Comment: Just use the directive in your template file `<h1 [navBar]>Hello {{name}}</h1>`. Remove `directive: [NavbarComponent]` from component decorator and try.

Comment: I tried but not working

Answer (score 1):

We have to import in app.model.ts file

**import { NavbarComponent} from './navbar.component';**

and

**declarations: [ AppComponent,NavbarComponent ],**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent} from './navbar.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,NavbarComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and in app.component.ts just call selector

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
                <p>Hello once again</p>
                <navbar></navbar>

  `
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says `'directive'` does not exist in type `'Component'`.

The component argument does not take a parameter of type directive. If you would like to see your newly created `navbar` in your `app.component.html` just remove the `directive` from `app.component.ts` and add the `navbar` selector in you app.component.html (make sure to have some html in your `navbar` template to make sure it is working).

```
<nabar><\navbar>
```

Comment: I removed directive and added <navbar></navbar>, now the error is not there but the output is not coming. just showing " Loading AppComponent content here ... "